# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matploitlib' in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed the `matploitlib` in my python37 environment,

[image]

but when I run my jupyter script , I still get error:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matploitlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/qp/h96_smbd55ggtzwvml8wpl9h0000gn/T/ipykernel_53343/2169616448.py in <module>
      1 import cv2
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import matploitlib.pyplot as plt
      4 import imutils

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matploitlib'
```

Comment: You have a typo. Try instead: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have made typo in your code (if the environment is correct) or you have chosen the wrong environment where `matplotlib` is absent.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Try with this in your code. If still it gives `ModuleNotFoundError`, then change your environment to your desired one where `matplotlib` is there.